# program not running on Big Sur - worked on all 10.x.x

Tags: iokit, macos-big-sur

I have an application that works fine on all Version 10.x.x mac pro computers. When I updated to Big Sur - it no longer runs.  The error I get is:

dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit

I there a library I need to load for Big Sur ?
Did the library name change and I need to do something ?

What do I do now ?

Jerry

Comment: To be clear, is this your own program (or open source) and you can change it, or is this an app developed by someone else, and you are a user? This is a programming Q&A site, so only the former case is covered here. (And if the latter, I'm afraid you will need to get in touch with the developer of the app, there is not likely much you can do unless you have the source code.)

Comment: If this is your own program or an open source program, is this an Xcode project or using some other build system? How is the IOKit Framework linked (e.g. in the project's "Build Phases" section in Xcode)? What SDK are you building with? Any other runtime or build time messages?

Comment: If you haven't got sufficient reputation to reply with comments (or if it makes sense in general) you can edit your question to add requested information.

Comment: From your now-deleted answer-which-wasn't-an-answer I see that you have an Xcode project. Perhaps you could edit your question to include a screenshot of how you've linked agains IOKit.framework. I assure you the framework is alive and well on Big Sur and I have multiple projects which link against it and continue running on the new OS version, so the problem must be specific to your project in some way. Perhaps you could also show us exactly how and where you are seeing this error.